# jQuery ajax load a page with an automatic download

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that produces a PDF and automatically downloads the file.

I have to submit some variables to the page for the PDF be produced. Right now I have it submitting a form using jQuery like this `$("#expForm").submit();`. I am submitting form jQuery because I have to apply some logic before the form is submitted.

This works fine and a PDF pops up right away.

The problem is I need to have some sort of loading icon come up because the exporting page loads a lot of data and I do not want to confuse the user.

I tried doing this using `$.post('exp.html', $("#expForm").serialize() ,function(data) {});`

The export page loads but it does not pop up the PDF. If I open the link from Firebug's console the PDF then loads.

Does anyone know of a way to make it auto download the PDF with using the `$.post()`

Any help on this would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return the path to pdf file in the response, and redirect in the success handler

```
$.post('exp.html', $("#expForm").serialize() ,function(data) {
location.href='path/to/pdf';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using something close to this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using `$.post()` but you can use a hidden `iframe` and have a form which will submit the data to iframe.

With this approach you can show progress bar or a loading icon until the server responds. And then you can hide the progress bar on `iframe`'s `load` event.